# Accessing the results from CURL request

Tags: php, curl

Im making a CURL request in PHP, and trying to echo the ID result.

```
$responseData = request();
echo $responseData["id"];
```

The results are

```
{
  "result":{
    "code":"000.200.100",
    "description":"successfully created checkout"
  },
  "buildNumber":"3b5605d6df9e6068ff1e9b178947fc41e641456e@2019-11-26 03:42:27 +0000",
  "timestamp":"2019-11-27 13:19:29+0000",
  "ndc":"B244D47DBFAD13EDEF126C980A711C8D.uat01-vm-tx02",
  "id":"B244D47DBFAD13EDEF126C980A711C8D.uat01-vm-tx02"
}
```

But when trying to get the ID i am getting the error

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in \public\payment\index.php on line 25
```

Comment: It should be echo $responseData->id;

Comment: I tried that too i get Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in \public\payment\index.php on line 25

Comment: have you decoded the result using json_decode()?

Comment: @GazSmith Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON can easily be parsed in PHP using `json_decode()`. There is an optional flag to decode the JSON into an object or an array.

Decode as an object:

```
$json = request();
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->id;
```

Decode as an array:

```
$json = request();
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo $data['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can decode you json using json_decode and then access the id variable like you are doing will be good for you.

```
$data = request(); 
$responseData = json_decode($data);
echo $responseData["id"];
```

Comment: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Yes I mean to convert the response into an array using json_decode